# How to extract second level keys out of two level map using lodash

Tags: lodash

I have a data structure like this

```
{ 
  'a' : { 'aa' : { b: 1, c: 2}},
  'b' : { 'bb' : { c: 3, d: 4}},
  'c' : { 'cc' : { c: 3, d: 4}}
}
```

I'd like to map it using `lodash` into a flat structure like this:

```
{
  'aa' : { b: 1, c: 2}},
  'bb' : { c: 3, d: 4}},
  'cc' : { c: 3, d: 4}},
}
```

I can do it using a side effect based approach with the code like this:

```
const flattened = {};
_(state.values)
  .map(e => _.forEach(e, (e, k) => flattened[k] = e))
  .value();
```

It does the job,  but I am looking for a nicer pure functional way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the values of the original object, and merge them into a new object:

```js
const obj = { 
  'a' : { 'aa' : { b: 1, c: 2}},
  'b' : { 'bb' : { c: 3, d: 4}},
  'c' : { 'cc' : { c: 3, d: 4}}
}
 
const result = _.merge({}, ..._.values(obj))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```